# Using Spring Integration HttpInbound example

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-integration

I am trying to use Spring-integration inside Spring-boot app in order to download HTTP file and save it to disk.
I couldnt find any example of doing so.
looking at the docs I found this:

```
<bean id="httpInbound"
  class="org.springframework.integration.http.inbound.HttpRequestHandlingController">
  <constructor-arg value="true" /> <!-- indicates that a reply is expected -->
  <property name="requestChannel" ref="httpRequestChannel" />
  <property name="replyChannel" ref="httpReplyChannel" />
  <property name="viewName" value="jsonView" />
  <property name="supportedMethodNames" >
    <list>
      <value>GET</value>
      <value>DELETE</value>
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>
```

Still not sure how to connect all the dots. How dynamically I am sending the URL path?

I only found http outbound example.

The scenario is pretty simple. just send via channel a file path to download and thats it

Any practical example?
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This sample should help you: https://github.com/artembilan/si-http-download-excel-sample.

Yes, it is without Boot, but there is no difference: just add Boot Plugin to the Gradle with `spring-boot-starter-web` and your app will be web-app with embedded Tomcat.

Comment: I payed attention u using there web.xml. in my spring-boot app i am not using web.xml. how will I add the servlet?

Comment: Spring Boot does that for you - the default `DispatcherServlet`. You just need to specify the desired `path` for the `<http:inbound-gateway>`.